# Spring 4 - run method after server starts

Tags: java, spring

I need to run some code just after server starts. I used ServletContextListener and it worked good, however... it run the code before server started. Because of that I got the timeout exception on server as it cannot start because my method is still running. There is no point in increasing the timeout time as this method takes about 1 hour. What should I do?

Comment: If the problem is that method takes 1 hour to execute, run it asynchronously in a different thread.

Comment: It's not a problem. Problem is how to tell Spring to execute this code when server starts.

Comment: Can you run it in @PostConstruct annotated method? You can run it asynchronously by calling a runnable from you annotated method.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I'm not sure if I understand you. I should just put this annotation above my method, Nothing more in configuration is needed?

Comment: Do some homework. read a tutorial how to save info in a pojo and make it available to a task running in another thread. then kick of that task from inside your ServletContextListener

Comment: Actually there is no need even to create a listener. Put your code in a component, in a method annotated by @PostConstruct (this should be scanned of course by spring). Spring will load all singelton beans when starting an application, so your code will be executed automatically.

Comment: Look at my answer below. You don't need any listener and you can configure this as one of your spring bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ApplicationListener`

```
    public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

      public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = event.getApplicationContext();
        (new Thread() {
           public void run() {
             // do stuff
           }
         }).start();
      }

    }
```

Just register that as a Spring bean. As suggested in the comments, you can execute the code on another thread.

Answer (score 4):

For better clarity, this is how you can do @PostConstruct. Put the below code in any of you config singleton bean defined in spring. For more details read what and how Postconstruct works. This should help you to load async after server is started.

```
    public class singletonBeanConfig{
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();

private class SampleConfigurator implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run you process here.            
        }

    }

@PostConstruct
    public final void initData() {
        // this will be executed when the config singleton is initialized completely.
        this.simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.execute(new SampleConfigurator());
    }
}
```